# Update, set a field value relative to subset of rows

Tags: mysql

I'm adding a new column `position` to a table. This column should hold a unique value within all rows with the same `userId`. It doesn't really matter if they're ordered by id, creation or just randomly. For instance:

```
id  userId  time    subn    position    created
1   1       33      FG      1           2016-08-13
2   1       57      FG      2           2016-08-15
3   1       20      XM      3           2016-08-11
4   2       81      FG      1           2016-08-01
5   3       12      FG      1           2016-08-27
6   3       33      FG      2           2016-08-18
```

How can I do this? I've tried creating a copy table (so that MySQL doesn't complain of target the target table for update being specified in from), setting the initial value to 0 and running this:

```
UPDATE userTimes_copy uic 
    SET position = (SELECT 1 + MAX(uic2.position) 
                    FROM userTimes uic2 
                    WHERE uic.userId = uic2.userId);
```

But it doesn't work. The first two rows, that have the same userId, get 486 (I have 485 rows) in position, and all of the rest 1.

Comment: The `userId` itself is already unique for each user, so why do you need a random value in `position`?  Note that it would be difficult to even use `random` here because of the replacement problem.

Comment: `id` is unique, not `userId`

Comment: @Shadow `This column should hold a unique value within all rows with the same userId` ... i.e. the same value for a group of user ID values.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `userId` is not unique in this table. Look at the example I wrote.